# ¿Por qué VBA no me admite decimales?

Tags: excel, vba

espero que se encuentren bien. Tengo una macro que cuenta valores mayores al valor de una variable (`Nm`) dada una celda y un rango, y luego coloca el conteo en la celda. Si `Nm=2`, me hace el conteo perfecto, pero si `Nm` tiene decimales siempre me pone en la celda que hay `0` valores mayores a tal variable cuando no es así.

Estoy seguro de que el problema está en lo que escribí en la fórmula pero necesito una segundo opinión. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
Dim Nm as Double
Dim Celda, Rango As Range

Set Celda = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")
Set Rango = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C1:C4")

Nm = 2.1

Celda.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rango, ">" & Nm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es curioso la verdad.

Al declarar la variable `Nm` como `Double`, le estás dando un tratamiento numérico. Por otro lado, VBA trabaja en formato inglés y por eso tienes puesto `Nm = 2.1`. PEro si trabajas en español, en realidad el motor de Excel lo lee como `2,1`, usando la coma como separador decimal. Si miras el valor temporal de la variable, verás que lo devuelve con coma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo correcto. Sin embargo, en el criterio de los COUNTIF lo pone con la coma y entonces no puede tratarlo VBA como debe ser, que sería con el punto. Sé que es un poco confuso, pero si sustituyes la línea

`Celda.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rango, ">" & Nm)` por `Celda.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rango, ">2.1")` verás que funciona perfectamente.

Así que lo que tienes que hacer es utilizar un `Replace`:

> [Función
> Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function)

El siguiente código funciona correctamente en mi PC:

```
Sub test()
Dim Nm As Double
Dim Celda As Range, Rango As Range

Set Celda = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")
Set Rango = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C1:C4")

Nm = 2.1

Celda.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rango, ">" & Replace(Nm, ",", "."))
End Sub
```

La verdad es que es una situación muy específica donde hay que usar triquiñuelas. Muy curioso el tratamiento decimal, la verdad.